# Button active,focus not working on Mac FireFox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problems with Mac Firefox/Chrome/Safari and Window/Chrome when I create a button with active, hover and focus. The hover works but the active and focus do not. All three of them work perfectly only on Window/Firefox.
I used css to do it. Any suggestion ?

Here is my CSS:

```
.navList button:hover,
.navList button:active,
.navList button:focus{ /* Changed */
border-color: black; 
border-style: solid;
background: rgb(73,155,234); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(73,155,234) 0%, rgb(32,124,229) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(73,155,234)), color-       stop(100%,rgb(32,124,229))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(73,155,234) 0%,rgb(32,124,229) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(73,155,234) 0%,rgb(32,124,229) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(73,155,234) 0%,rgb(32,124,229) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgb(73,155,234) 0%,rgb(32,124,229) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#499bea', endColorstr='#207ce5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Here is html:

```
<ul id="List" class="navList">
<button id="eButton" class="moduleButton">Employees</button>
<button id="iButton" class="moduleButton">Inventory</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: My suggestion is put the problem code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It makes easier for us to help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to stick to a certain chronological order of the pseudo classes:

1. `:link`
2. `:visited`
3. `:focus`
4. `:hover`
5. `:active`

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes for more details.